# keep controls in one line in Form Tag

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<div class="btn-group text-center" role="group" aria-label="...">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Baking Needs</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Butter & Margarine</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Cereals</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Chocolates & Sweets</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Desserts</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Jams, Spreads & Honey</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">On-The-Go Breakfast</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Snacks</button>
</div>
```

and this is output 
[image]

but i need to each single button be http post so i added form tag for each single one

```html
<div class="btn-group text-center" role="group" aria-label="...">
<form action="/products/Products?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loader-wrapper" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="totop" data-ajax-update="#target" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="4D0GUkUdUmtNh2qszu7jlDdJYN9zkn03VUCqbzTsCXOzsElILKPbZFwHIeFiuDs5YiYAEl9wnOHvSeyG4OvCWGCPnJvfZFyve6agI-kk9IE1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Baking Needs" name="cat2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Breakfast, Sweets, Snacks & Baking Needs" name="catone"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Baking Needs</button>
</form>
<form action="/products/Products?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loader-wrapper" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="totop" data-ajax-update="#target" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="hhbHAlHOALneInNttvDc-kl62hIv7Gb7IzcTTJ3TO_DmcAT3SnO09v0i4vTiuD2TZseIfEVVo1SNxTjIfhNy_Ia5Sj3Z6GA030tjZWGsDUM1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Butter & Margarine" name="cat2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Breakfast, Sweets, Snacks & Baking Needs" name="catone"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Butter & Margarine</button>
</form>
<form action="/products/Products?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loader-wrapper" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="totop" data-ajax-update="#target" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="QTt0sRQAOR5Cgz8bSttkIlXOHqNwz4P5-g6cmabhTDXd6Hsq-tT7wXfsO2ny9siYvYFb216L0sOuClvA0fu05jEMkK_FaEOALuz_A5hwNr01"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Cereals" name="cat2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Breakfast, Sweets, Snacks & Baking Needs" name="catone"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Cereals</button>
</form>
<form action="/products/Products?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loader-wrapper" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="totop" data-ajax-update="#target" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="vio4Y6Fbf43AUpQt-ju7mhwqVaNxJIENseV6VMju7WtMawxZqjzKr-589HTVkMUAzpyjdkpG3_oTDaCPwqR4IZ32yjGccJeZnlLOh2FbyTk1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Chocolates & Sweets" name="cat2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Breakfast, Sweets, Snacks & Baking Needs" name="catone"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Chocolates & Sweets</button>
</form>
<form action="/products/Products?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loader-wrapper" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="totop" data-ajax-update="#target" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="f-tNNpOdY4EszpI7vbToaMpWLyEl5HYgvRUFI_LF-XTuQLlturllVKr4nG9U3Xlk8ngJcEqTYwQanf420YIIyV3azoB66X_tIB87gw33RMQ1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Desserts" name="cat2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Breakfast, Sweets, Snacks & Baking Needs" name="catone"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Desserts</button>
</form>
<form action="/products/Products?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loader-wrapper" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="totop" data-ajax-update="#target" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="ob61jF6XaN-6II-w1Nzf9o9q5HOaBbyGfCXEUNpDlyV4Kb9FXywbDDv31LGGt1xFp4XYVVTmhfLmUEu_jFV48i4yZ9qC7IFZhijLgNIgvmQ1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Jams, Spreads & Honey" name="cat2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Breakfast, Sweets, Snacks & Baking Needs" name="catone"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Jams, Spreads & Honey</button>
</form>
<form action="/products/Products?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loader-wrapper" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="totop" data-ajax-update="#target" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="6Fdjn_PX4giauZ2bHBxFWp2oQPzqaZB7v7hmLk3htboLYfMCS_spxb9HtTRlHhdUGqhbqCEtFNUe2INbFTwqDYiQQDRgx68XLUfVNoUS8pQ1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="On-The-Go Breakfast" name="cat2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Breakfast, Sweets, Snacks & Baking Needs" name="catone"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">On-The-Go Breakfast</button>
</form>
<form action="/products/Products?Length=8" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loader-wrapper" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="totop" data-ajax-update="#target" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="uTB3f6J_sN3FMq7BFRjAoiUTR4LmFhWgMD9XHEzeasUJCAPG9YUu2HXU2s2ZmnixEkm253oPCvEGSZ_xTX8PLVAmYmUMsa1-SYYgZC4VUsE1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Snacks" name="cat2"/>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Breakfast, Sweets, Snacks & Baking Needs" name="catone"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-purple">Snacks</button>
</form>
</div>
```

but result became :

[image]

is there any way to have form Tag and keep buttons in one line as group ?

thanks

Comment: You can try floating the forms and setting explicit widths for each of them so that they are not 100% wide.

Comment: could you please , show me in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float each form so they are side-by-side and change the width so they aren't 100% wide.

```
form{
float:left;
display:inline-block; /*-this is so the form is only as wide as its content-*/
width:auto !important;/*-this is to override the width-*/
}
```

I think it might work without floating them, but I'm not too sure how Bootstrap styles forms.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3jpbg39x/)

Comment: Thanks , working, but small bug here that these buttons are not in group anymore, do you have any idea for this...     

http://postimg.org/image/ze1zd18yf/

Comment: what do you mean they are not in group?

Comment: if you check this image : 
http://postimg.org/image/ze1zd18yf/

there are  border radius that separate buttons , 

it would be great to look like this
http://i.stack.imgur.com/zvkFx.png

Comment: Get rid of the margin. `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: margin:0 auto; not working, but thanks for your time